# Finding the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)=(x+2)^{3/5}$ at $x=-2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> Does the graph of the function $f$ have tangent line at the given points? If yes, what is the tangent line?
>
> $f(x)=(x+2)^{3/5}$ at $x=-2$

solution: yes, $x=-2$

The derivative I found:

$$f'(x)=\frac 3{5(x+2)^\frac 25}$$

and then I get $f'(-2)=\frac 3{5\cdot 0}=\frac 30$ which is undefined.

anyone know how to go about this problem? I got the slope or whatever to be undefined or something, any tips/solution appreciated!

Comment: The slope is based on the derivative, so what is the derivative of $f$ at $x=-2$?  Have you graphed the function to see what it looks like at $x=-2$?

Comment: well that was exactly the thing I found to be undefined, I might have differentiated it wrong, idk

Comment: Please post the derivative you found as part of your question

Comment: (3)/(5)(x+2)^(2/5)) = 3/(5*0^(2/5)) = 3/0??

Comment: @sdfg123123 the tangent line will be a vertical tangent line. Please look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the slope, evaluate the derivative of your function at that specific point:

$$f(x) = (x+2)^{3/5}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{3}{5}*(x+2)^{-2/5}$$
$$f'(-2) = \frac{3}{5*0}  = \text{undefined}$$

Therefore, your tangent line will be the form $$x =a$$ where a is a constant.

It will be a vertical tangent line as well.

A line with a slope of $0$ will have the form $$y = a$$ And it will be a horizontal tangent line.

Since at x = -2 your slope is undefined, a = -2.

Therefore,

$$x = -2$$ is the tangent line.

Comment: You should explicitly write the content of your comment on the question as part of your answer.

Comment: ahh ok thanks! this is always the method when you get undefined slope? if yes then im wondering, when does the function not have a tangent line? slope = 0?

Comment: @abiessu what are you referring to

Comment: @sdfg123123 whenever you have an undefined slope, the tangent line will be in the form $x = a$, where a is a constant. Similarly, when the slope = 0, it will have the form y = a, where a is a constant as well.

Comment: Your comment on the question actually states that the tangent line will be vertical, but you do not state that in your answer here.

Comment: @abiessu oh okay I'll add that

Comment: ahh ok, if m=0, x=0, y=0 then its no tangent line? or what :P

Comment: @sdfg123123 if $m = 0$, then your slope is 0. If $(0,0)$ is a point on this line, then since $y =a$, $a = 0$, and so your equation is $y = 0$

Comment: ahh ok thanks!!

Comment: @sdfg123123: some functions have no tangent line because they are not differentiable at a given point, for instance $f(x)=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @sdfg123123 if you are content with my answer, please feel free to check it

Comment: @sdfg123123 what abiessu is saying is also correct. Some functions may not have tangent lines because the derivative doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Try evaluating the gradient at points very close to $x = -2$, and see what happens as you approach $x$, to get some hints!

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$f(x)=\sqrt[5]{(x+2)^3}=(x+2)^\frac 35$$

we should get

$$f'(x)=\frac 35(x+2)^\frac {-2}5=\frac 35\sqrt[5]{(x+2)^{-2}}$$

as the derivative.

You have correctly found that $f'(-2)$ goes to $+\infty$, but perhaps using the inverse function will solve that difficulty:

$$g(y)=x=y^\frac 53-2\\
g'(y)=\frac 53 y^\frac 23$$

At $x=-2, f(-2)=0$, so we plug in $y=0$ to $g'(0)=0$ and find that the slope is defined and is $0$ for the inverse function, therefore we can definitely say that the tangent line exists and is $x=-2$.